# How to prevent login more than once from same user in nodejs chat application?

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I'm using `Socket.io` and `Express` to make a chat application.

The chat is anonymous and I don't want to save anything in any database. I can think of checking the IP address of the user and prevent another login from the same IP address, but I don't think that's a good idea, because people are online with shared IP addresses. Another thing would be session id, but that changes even when the user logs in from a different tab in browser. Is there any easy way to do this without using any database? Preferably without installing any other package/lib?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I did and worked for me. It's not much different from Andreas' answer:

```
var MemoryStore = express.session.MemoryStore;
var sessionStore = new MemoryStore();
app.configure(function() {
    //app.use(express.logger());
    app.use(express.cookieParser());
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(express.session({ 
            store: sessionStore, 
            secret: 'someSecret',
            key: 'cookie.sid', maxAge: null }));
            });

var sessionID;
var sessionArray = new Array();
var sessionIDs = new Array();
```

In my 'login' function I have:

```
sessionArray = socket.handshake.headers.cookie.split(" ");
sessionID = sessionArray[0].split("express.sid=").pop();

if(sessionIDs.indexOf(sessionID) > -1) {
   io.sockets.socket(socket.id).emit('preventlogin', true);
}
else {
   sessionIDs.push(sessionID);
   // and do the rest
}
```

And on 'disconnect' I do:

```
var ind = sessionIDs.indexOf(sessionID);
sessionIDs.splice(ind, 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

The express.session middleware uses cookie-based sessions, which by default are only stored in memory and not in a database. A cookie-based session won't change if the user opens up new tab. [This article](http://www.danielbaulig.de/socket-ioexpress/) is mentioned elsewhere on SO as a good reference for using express sessions with socket.io. In general you just have to check the session when authorizing in socket.io (`sio.set('authorization', authCallback)`) and the do however your app works to make the user connect to the right room.

**Update:** (more specific on how to block users with a cookie)

```
// Var to save if the user is connected or not
var connectedUsers = [];

sio.authorization(function(data, next){
  var cookie = data.headers.cookie && data.headers.cookie.match(/auth=([^;]+)/);
  cookie = cookie && cookie[1] || null;

  if (cookie && connectedUsers.indexOf(cookie)){
    next(null, false);
  }
  else {
    connectedUsers.push(cookie);
    next(null, cookie);
  }
});

// Somewhere else
socket.on('disconnect', function (data) {
  var cookie = data.headers.cookie && data.headers.cookie.match(/auth=([^;]+)/);
  cookie = cookie && cookie[1] || null;

  if(cookie) {
    connectedUsers.splice(connectedUsers.indexOf(cookie), 1);
  }
});
```

This is a very basic way to get the value of the cookie, but it's worked for me. Note that I haven't had time to try this solution, but the principle should work.

Comment: I looked everywhere and I can't find a single working code snippet working. These frameworks/packages change so often...

Comment: Without knowing more about how your app works and why it needs sessions I can't give a more specific answer. The linked article is indeed for express 2.x instead of 3.x, but the principles are the same.

Comment: I just want to block users who are already connected. So somewhere in my on('connection', function() {}); I can check if this user/session already exists. With normal socket.id it doesn't work because socket.id changes even from another tab.

Comment: @Loolooii i added an example that should work for blocking users

Comment: Sorry, I accepted my own answer, because I'm 100% sure it worked for me. Yours looks a lot like mine, except I don't use authorization. Your solution is more elegant.