# How to prevent login more than once from same user in nodejs server?

Tags: android, server

My question is the same as this one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15327735/how-to-prevent-login-more-than-once-from-same-user-in-nodejs-chat-application) but with little bit of difference, the difference is that i'am using the nodeJs server as a backend for my android app, also i am not using sockets, anyone got an idea about this ?
i want to restrict multiple connection as the same time from a user.

Answer (score 0):

You must be maintaining sessionId/token for all the logged-in users, right?
When any user tries to log in from the device, you simply invalidate (remove) all of their previous sessionIds.
As simple as that.

Example:
User A installs App on Google Pixel, Logs In, A session/token abc123 is created for him which will allow him to access all the other APIs.
User A keeps the app as it is & installs app on Samsung Device, Logs In with the same credentials, at this time, server will check that user already has some token/session, delete and clear all those session/token, and give new token in response.

So now, User A will be able to use App in Samsung device, but when he will try to open app in Google Pixel, APIs will fail and he won't be able to use app.

Additionally, you can log out user manually if the session/token is invalid for 3 api calls.