# How to prevent multiple logins from the same user in a REST API?

Tags: postgresql, rest, express, authentication, prisma

How can I prevent a user that is logged in from logging into their account from a different device?

I am working on a mobile app, where the rest api should prevent the user from logging into more than one device,similar to how Netflix does that, where you cannot watch in more than two screens at a time for example. What would be safest way to implement it?

I am using express as framework, prisma as ORM, and PostgreSQL as my database.

Comment: You need to get the device_id sent by the front end for every time the user logs in and validate the back end where if the device_id in the database is different from the device_id sent, then it fails to login

Comment: Kind of similar to what you need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15327735/how-to-prevent-login-more-than-once-from-same-user-in-nodejs-chat-application